# How do I handle xslt script code samples?

Tags: xml, xslt, xerces

I'm getting fatal error http://www.w3.org/2006/xqt-errors#XPTY0004 in XSLT scripts I've created using Notepad, UltraEdit or Help text published to the web. These tools show nothing no strange characters, but the script breaks unless I manually edit the input so it is all on one line (usually need tor recreate every blank character). Tedious for cut'n'paste code samples. Is the (XERCES?) parser interpreting some illegal character that doesn't display in these tools?

I've tried adding `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` as the first line of a script, but that doesn't help. Anyone who can explain why the XML parser doesn't get past the http://www.w3.org/2005/xqt-errors#XPTY0004 (try the link).

Comment: XML parser error: Element type "xsl:stylesheet" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"  The stylesheet element NEEDS to have multiple (4 or more) namespace delcarations. It only reads 1.

Answer (score 0):

the only possible character that you can get in those tools not to be rendered is the CR because you are working on windows. Try using a text editor that allows you to just use new lines with no CR (Jedit is an example)